# что означает '->' в некоторых функциях?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Иногда натыкаюсь как некоторые используют -> в своих функциях. Искал в нэте, но толковой информации не нашел, можете объяснить для чего этот знак используется?

Comment: аннотации типов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Явно указывает возвращаемый функцией тип. По сути нужно для большего понимания кода при прочтении. Также, вроде бы эти аннотации можно считывать и преобразовывать вывод в указанный тип.

Точно также можно указать типы для переменных:

```py
a: int = 1
b: str = 'текст'
```

Функция, для сложения 2 чисел может выглядеть вот так:

```py
def sum_(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b
```

Но типы из аннотаций не обязательно соблюдать. Например, если передать `float`, то никаких проблем не будет и вернется тоже `float`:

```py
print(type(sum_(1.2, 2.5)))
```

```
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: Вернётся то вернётся, на том эта история и закончится.

Comment: а понял, получается я бы мог просто написать def sum(a, b):   return (a+b)? Одним словом показывает какой тип возвращает функция

Comment: Да, верно. Некоторые библиотеки (например discord-py) умеют считывать указанные типы аргументов в функциях команд и преобразовывать полученные из текста сообщения данные к ним

Answer (score 1):

В большинстве случаев это что функция возвращает тип данных в соответствии с типом, указанным ниже.